# OData model versioning

Tags: sapui5

I've looked into many platforms to find the difference between all version of OData in terms of CRUD operations.However, could not find the relevant answer.

could someone please explain me the same.

Thanks you!

Comment: CRUD operations are the same. What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: in terms of order of execution

Comment: see [V2 vs V4 difference list](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/abd4d7c7548d4c29ab8364d3904a6d74.html)